# Connect query with every php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

If I have

```
$logger = $_SESSION['logger'];
$postquery = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = $postquery->fetch_object()){

    $posts[] = $row;


}
```

And then:

```
    foreach($posts as $post):?>
    <div class="post"><?php 
echo '<div class="text">'.$post->text.'</div><textarea id='comment'></textarea>';
```

Now jquery and ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#comment').keypress(function(event) {
                var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (key == 13) {
                    var comment = $('#comment').val();      
                    var postid = '<?php echo $post->id; ?>';
                    var from = '<?php echo $logger; ?>';

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "intodb.php",
                        data: {c: comment, p: postid, f: from},
                        success: function(status) {

                            $('#comment').val('');

                        }

                    });
                    };
                }); 

        });
    </script>
```

Inside intodb.php:

```
$c =$_POST['comment'];
$p =$_POST['postid'];
$f =$_POST['from'];
$insert = "INSERT INTO comment (id, comment, from, for) VALUES ('','$c','$f','$p')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
     echo "commented....";
}
```

Now I have problem that jquery use only last output from database as values...
I have here outputed 5 posts and if i comment on first second third or fourth. The insert is everywhere for each one as I commented only at post five.
Also I have readed js works with classes but when I change this to class:

```
$('.comment')  AND <textarea class='comment'>
```

My script does not work... Can someone help me with this I was trying to do it like 3 days... Also if you can help me try it by your self first if you can because I asked few times questions here and answers was add things that does not matter... I looked up many other questions and answers but it seems like it wont work on me....

I have this problem every where for every script like if i have few products fetched from database and for each on hover I need to display some text. It works only for one of them...

UPDATE: On this pic I have reply btn and on click the textarea should be seen.. It works only on first fetch from database... On others js code does not work... Why is that???
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var postid = '<?php echo $post->id; ?>';
var from = '<?php echo $logger; ?>';
```

This is normal. Your postid will always be one value. You need to loop through your post and make a javascript array with it.

Though it's a bad practice to do it.

You should put a reference to your html id with your database id.

Imagine you have something like that

```
<div id="my-post-1" class="post">Some Text</div>
<div id="my-post-3" class="post">Some Text Again</div>
<div id="my-post-5" class="post">Some Text Again</div>
```

Now you have a reference between your database and your client and everything become easier

```
$('.post').click(function() {
  var postid = this.id.split('-')[2]
})
```

I'm a bit rusty with jquery but that should help

Comment: Okay then what should I do ?

Comment: Well my bad i didn't understand what do you want. Your postid do not have to be send to the server. Mysql will create one for you. Just make sure to send it back to your client so he can edit his post or delete.

hope i'm clear.

Comment: It is not about editing his post it is about doing anything with jquery for every code it works only on one fetch from database how can I make it work on all I have a similar problem with button forr reply .. I have hidden textarea wich will be seen after the click on reply button and it works only at first database fetch not all of them I will also add pic of that in my question....

Comment: I'll edit my post wait 5 minute. I think i understand what you want

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working on my host ill try on localhost and Ill see if it worrks for some basic fetch.. Ill let u know

Comment: Your <textarea class='comment'> need to have the id of your bdd to work as i did on my edit. Do not try to put some php hack on your javascript you don't need.